# Delete files older than x days in multiple folders

Tags: windows

I have a folder structure that is something like this:

```
C:\XYZ\
|---A\
|-----Archive
|---B\
|-----Archive
|---C\
|-----Archive
```

There are a total of about 150 folders.  I run the command below to see what files are in the folders:

```
for /R C:\XYZ\ %i IN ("archive\*.*") do echo %i
```

I want to modify this command to delete all files in the archive folders older that a number of days. I tried the `/d -20` somewhere in the command line to try and get the files just listed, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, following command will help you:

`ForFiles /p "c:\XYZ" /s /d -20 /M Archive.* /c "cmd /c del @file"`

For further help, please take reference from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Note: Please backup your content before experimenting any command :D

Comment: @Hansie Lategan, Please accept the answer if this solve ur problem, or let me know if modification needs to be done

Comment: @shivram seth I don't think it will work.  The structure is actually

    c:\xyz\a\archive\*.*
    c:\xyz\b\archive\*.*

There are also subfolders under the \a \b etc folders.  Sorry I am battling with the editing  Cannot get it to highlight the code.  Tries to read how to do it and cannot get it right

Comment: @Hansie, i thought /s flag will iterate through all sub directories, and then delete Archieve.* there,. If you have not tried can u check it once atleast

Comment: @shivram I tested and it does not work as it is looking for files with the name 'archive" and not searching in the archive folder.